# Django model objects and Graphene get_node

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python

So far I was able to play around with Graphene without needing `DjangoObjectType`. I try to avoid it as I'm not planning to stay too close to my Django model classes. However I'm having issues when implementing Relay with Graphene:

```
class HouseholdNode(graphene.ObjectType):
  class Meta:
    interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node,)

  name = graphene.String()

  @classmethod
  def get_node(cls, info, id):
    return Household.objects.get(pk=id)
```

This fails with the following error:

> Abstract type Node must resolve to an Object type at runtime for field Query.node with value "Test", received "None".

"Test" comes straight from `Household`'s `__str__` function.

Next try:

```
  @classmethod
  def get_node(cls, info, id):
    return cls(Household.objects.get(pk=id))
```

`cls` is `HouseholdNode`. However this yields the wrong result:

```
"node": {
  "id": "SG91c2Vob2xkOlRlc3Q=",
  "name": null
}
```

The ID is actually "Test".

**Solution that works:**

```
  @classmethod
  def get_node(cls, info, id):
    household = Household.objects.get(pk=id)
    return cls(name=household.name)
```

However I highly doubt that this is all Graphene can do for me. Do I really have to wrap the real data object into `HouseholdNode`? I already have resolve functions, can't those simply be used instead?

The documentation is highly lacking on those edges, please enlighten me.

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/654) on Github is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Abstract Types (like `graphene.relay.node.Node`) are resolved by the [executor](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphql-core/blob/b3a6bd0f89651af10a937e5270e46c696672a2e5/graphql/execution/executor.py#L401) using [`graphql.execution.executor.complete_abstract_value`](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphql-core/blob/b3a6bd0f89651af10a937e5270e46c696672a2e5/graphql/execution/executor.py#L446).

Practically speaking, your ObjectTypes with `Node` as an interface are passed up from graphene to the graphql layer, each wrapped as a [`GrapheneInterfaceType`](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/blob/master/graphene/types/typemap.py#L187). The [`resolve_type`](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/blob/master/graphene/types/typemap.py#L40) of each of those objects (which ultimately provides the source of your error) calls [`graphql.execution.executor.get_default_resolve_type_fn`](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphql-core/blob/master/graphql/execution/executor.py#L487).

This function narrows down the possible types which could be returned (`possible_types`) and then iterates over those types checking if the `is_type_of` attribute is callable and whether it returns True. It's important to note that the `possible_types` are user-defined subclasses of `Node`, inheriting from `graphene.types.objecttype.ObjectType` which has [`is_type_of = None`](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/blob/2594cdb61409f8ecedf0958ee959f8f8ded3efbc/graphene/types/objecttype.py#L63). Ergo, you get the [`GraphQLError`](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphql-core/blob/master/graphql/execution/executor.py#L464) as no type is resolved.

The solution is to define a `is_type_of` method on your object types (or create an abstract ObjectType you can subclass with this already implemented). For example, [here is the code](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-sqlalchemy/blob/a2fe9263d73b3baccd63b192b983cda5abfb88f0/graphene_sqlalchemy/types.py#L144) in `graphene-sqlalchemy` that implements the `is_type_of` logic, and for `graphene-django` that [code is here](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/blob/c0edb0c927fb5206c3747e0cce40984c2c4d9d49/graphene_django/types.py#L103).

```
@classmethod
def is_type_of(cls, root, info):
    if isinstance(root, SimpleLazyObject):
        root._setup()
        root = root._wrapped
    if isinstance(root, cls):
        return True
    if not is_valid_django_model(type(root)):
        raise Exception((
            'Received incompatible instance "{}".'
        ).format(root))

    model = root._meta.model._meta.concrete_model
    return model == cls._meta.model
```